# Editing Default Opportunity Team on User record = usersalesteamedit.jsp

Tags: schema, salesforce

When you add/edit a User's Default Opportunity Team, a SF-native page comes up  - usersalesteamedit.jsp.   That page has a checkbox with the following label: "Automatically add my default opportunity team to opportunities that I create or open opportunities that are transferred to me".

How do I access this checkbox programmatically?  Which object is it on?

Comment: You might also want to cross-post this question to http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I asked this to Salesforce support a few months ago (before winter 13 release with improvements) and they indicated those fields aren't available via the API.